# How to get code from another file and write everything to one file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to use htmlspecialchars but it only accepts the address of the file, can I make it accept the code and not the address?

```
return "<script src='" . htmlspecialchars('static/functions.js', ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "'" . nonce() . "></script>\n";


function nonce() {
    return ' nonce="' . get_nonce() . '"';
}


function get_nonce() {
    static $nonce;
    if (!$nonce) {
        $nonce = base64_encode(rand_string());
    }
    return $nonce;
}
```

Comment: why do you feel you need to run htmlspecialchars on your javascript code? Does it contain problematic content? If so, why can't you control it?

Comment: That runs `htmlspecialchars()` on the string `static/functions.js` NOT on the contents of the file called `static/functions.js`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` accepts only a _string_ value as first parameter - not “addresses”, and not anything else either. The _correct_ question to ask here would be, how do I get the contents of my JS file read into a string variable in PHP (and that is something you will hopefully be able to research on your own.)

Comment: understood nothing :)

Comment: @menfix ok, the point is that, unless you think your Javascript contains malicious code / HTML, you should not need to use htmlspecialchars to process it. And if it _does_ contain malicious stuff, why? it's your code, so fix it. You didn't explain why you think you need to do this at all. It sounds like either a technical misunderstanding or an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ADyson it is not malicious, just this function is such

Comment: "just this function is such"...what does that mean? Please explain more clearly, or show an example of what you are talking about. Also, in the comments below you said "I don’t want the functions.js file to exist"...but why? What's the problem with it? most web applications rely on JavaScript files. You seem to be going to a lot of trouble just to eliminate a JavaScript file, without any clear reason for doing so.

Comment: @ADyson there is a reason but not serious, I can use 2 files, but I wonder if it is possible not to use extra files and do the same.

Comment: well you can, but I don't see where htmlspecialchars would come into it, especially in the case of a JavaScript file. But really it's not a big deal to have a separate JavaScript file. If it was me I would find a more productive use of your time than working on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML `<script src=` is going to fetch a resource and run it, from wherever you have specified in the `src` attribute. It's expecting a URL.

The `htmlspecialchars(` function is expecting a string, and will return a string.

The way you have it right now, it will take the string `"static/functions.js"` and process it.

Your question suggests you want it to operate on the contenst of the file. This is techncially possible, but the file has to be fetched first.

`htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents(__DIR__ . 'static/functions.js') )`

But that still seems odd. You want to convert all the encoded special characters in your JavaScript file to their HTML entities? Like `<` to `&lt;`? That's almost surely going to make the JavaScript invalid.

Even if it didn't ruin your JavaScript, you'd still be trying to take the *contents* of that file and putting them in the `src` property of the `script` tag, which is expecting a URL.

Overall this seems like you need to step back and think about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

**Edit for OP question in comments**

```
<div>
  <span>Some regular HTML content</span>
</div>
<script>
  <?php 
      // we're now in PHP, about to store some JavaScript as a string
      $js = <<<EOD
console.log("I am a JavaScript console message!");
console.log("Me too!");
EOD; // note this can't be indentend or spaced, it has to be flush left


     // we can 'echo' the JavaScript directly into the HTML
      echo $js;
  ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Not really, I want to pull out the entire contents of the file and use the code without the file.
but I don’t know how in that case I can use htmlspecialchars

Comment: Then what you want to do is directly echo the contents into the HTML, inside of a <script> block, but not in the `src` of it. Something like, `<script><?php echo file_get_contents(__DIR__ . 'static/functions.js'); ?></script>`

Comment: but how to add my nonce function?

Comment: What do you want that to do?

Comment: I added on top what the `nonce` function does

Comment: Right...but you said you wanted to not have the file fetched by the browser, instead  having the JavaScript code directly put into the HTML. So what are you trying to accomplish with the nonce? Every time the php runs the server is going to fetch that JavaScript file and then output it, you don't need a cache-busting parameter on it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do everything in one file.
I don’t want the functions.js file to exist,
but at the same time my function worked the same way.

Comment: Why? It's not bad to have multiple files, in fact as things grow in complexity, it's much better. Technically you could copy and paste your JavaScript code into your PHP, then output it directly. Look up heredoc in PHP, which is a way to have a multiline string to preserve your formatting and quotes.

Comment: you can show an example of what you mean, I just do not catch the thoughts.

Comment: I still don’t understand how this will work with the function. nonce ().

Comment: What is the purpose of your function nonce? It looks like it is generating a random suffix to the file you wanted to fetch. However, this is not necessary if PHP is fetching the file instead of the client's browser.

Comment: unfortunately everything is much more complicated, I would not do so if it weren’t necessary. I need this function by default.

Comment: Right, but until you explain what you are expecting the nonce() function to accomplish, and why you feel it's necessary, we can't help you.

Comment: what you suggested using file_get_contents will not help me get rid of functions.js need some other way